# XCODE AVAudioPlayer error regarding AudioQueue: request to trim 0 + 1676 = 1676 frames from buffer containing 1152 frames

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, audioqueue

I am trying to play different sounds at different times. based on a button press or timer timeout etc.
Here is the code.

To play the sound function:

```
-(void)myPlaySound:(NSString *)mySoundFile NumberOfLoops:(int)loopsCount ofType:(NSString *)fileType
{


NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                           pathForResource:mySoundFile
                                           ofType:fileType]];

myAudio  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];

myAudio.volume = audioVolume;

myAudio.delegate = self;

myAudio.numberOfLoops = loopsCount;
[myAudio prepareToPlay];
 [myAudio play];

}
```

to stop the sound:

```
    if([myAudio isPlaying]){
        [myAudio stop];
        myAudio.currentTime = 0;
    }
```

Problem: At times I get this error : 
AudioQueue: request to trim 0 + 1676 = 1676 frames from buffer containing 1152 frames

The error happens as soon as [myAudio play] is called.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Any chance your 'myPlaySound' gets called while the audio plays? you should try and stop the player before allocating a different instance then.

Comment: I dont think I am calling my method while the player is called. BTW, when i try to load another sound file[in place of the existing one] this error is not happening. I am not sure, may be because the audio files are of different bit rates this is happening ?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem and like Radu said, the problem that I seemed to be having was trying to play a sound while it was already playing. I don't think it's a big deal if the sound gets replaced by another sound, but be careful that you're not trying to play the same sound while it is already playing.

Answer (score 3):

Chiming in a little late, but if you haven't solved your problem this might help.

If you stop `myAudio` before you play `myAudio` you could eliminate the problem.

So where you have:

```
    myAudio.numberOfLoops = loopsCount;
    [myAudio prepareToPlay];
    [myAudio play];
```

Try changing it to:

```
    [myAudio stop];
    myAudio.numberOfLoops = loopsCount;
    [myAudio prepareToPlay];
    [myAudio play];
```